# Magento2: How to remove compared product and recently ordered section from my account sidebar?

Tags: magento2

How to remove compared product and recently orderd section from my account sidebar as shown below 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**remove** attribute Allows to remove or cancel the removal of the element. When a container is removed, its child elements are removed as well. [For more info](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref)

You can find compare block code in below path.
`vendor/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

And for recently orderd block comes from below path.
`vendor/module-slaes/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Add below code to your theme or module **di.xml** file inside `<body></body>` tag.

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

Don't forgot to flush cache.

You can also remove the whole Addition info side bar by using `<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true">`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these blocks using the **remove** tag in the below file.

> /app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/> 
        <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

just override the default.xml

```
from  =>  vendor/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml 

to your theme =>  app/design/frontend/your/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

Then add the below code:

```
  <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
             <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
             <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
             <referenceBlock name="multiple-wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />           
             <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

OR remove all section:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true">
```